# How do I write code to deny a non-numeric input using I've tried argv[1][i] it doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I don't know where did I do wrong here my first time trying to use

```
int main(int argc,  argv[])
```

I just don't know if I'm using it correctly.

Here's some code:

1. The code compiles properly and does give me the result correctly as well

   ```
    encrypts "BaRFoo" as "FeVJss" using 4 as key
    Log
    running ./caesar 4...
    sending input BaRFoo...
    checking for output "ciphertext: FeVJss\n"...
   ```

BUT here is my problem: when I type in 2r or 4w or any non numeric key, I get this message：

> :( handles non-numeric key
> timed out while waiting for program to exit

Can anyone tell me how to add another loop for this function to get the numerical key to print as -Usage: ./caesar key . please ? Thanks very much an appreciate your help and useful advice.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Variable declarations
    bool keySuccessful = false;
    int key = 0;
    int input_length = 0;
    string text = "" ;
    // The number of command line args submitted was incorrect.
    do
    {
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key .\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
      // Convert ASCII char to a alphabate char
      // Access individual char in the string plain
      // get the key val and converted to integer
      key = atoi(argv[1]);
      keySuccessful = true;
      printf("%s",argv[1]);
    }
    }
    while(!keySuccessful);

    // get user input
    text = get_string("%s",text);
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    input_length = strlen(text);

        for (int i=0; i<input_length; i++)
        {
        // Checking if is the lowercase a=97 to z=112
        // Print out lower case with ky a=65 to z=90
           if(isupper(text[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", (((text[i] - 65) + key) % 26) + 65);
            }
            else if(islower(text[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", (((text[i] - 97) + key) % 26) + 97);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", text[i]);
            }
        }
    

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: look at `strtol` to be sure the argument is a valid number and to get its value, never use `atoi`

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to make sure the first argument is a number, and stop execution otherwise.
You could easily do that looping over the argument, and checking the output of `isdigit()` from `ctype.h` for each character, like this:

```
int argumentIsNumber = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) {
    if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) == 0) {
        argumentIsNumber = 0;
    }
}

if (argumentIsNumber == 0) {
    // Tell the user the introduced key is wrong
}
```

As you see in this example, you could set a flag to 1, and change it to 0 whenever a non-digit is found. Then, when the loop ends, you only have the flag to 1 if all the characters were digits.

Hope it helps!

Comment: tyvm i tried to use this  for loop but keep prmopt me with the error msg says: caesar.c:40:12: error: relational comparison result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-comparison] for (i < input_length ; i++); i tried use ```isdigit(argv[1][i])  !=0  ```as well tells me unidetified declaration

Comment: @echooca don’t forget the `#include <ctype.h>`

Comment: tks a lot i have a look at it again submitted wiz one error :)

Comment: @dieortin if the argument is 656752675635625365263526536536562536253642375689373652645736274 you will consider the argument is correct but *atoi* will not success. The right way is not that one, and you do not manage negative numbers too

Answer (score -1):

you should make code if user prompt somethink like

$ ./caesar 20x

you shoud print

Usage: ./caesar key

```
for (int i = 0 , n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
{
    if (isalpha(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1; 
        }
}
```

Comment: you wanted to do something different than the previous answer but your way to do is wrong,  for instance you consider 12@34 as a valid number. Read `isalpha` specification

Comment: @bruno tks for the contribution not sure if u can still see my reply on the closed question forgot to tag you so just want to send my thank you message here